# How to read the output variable from .net c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how can I read the output variable from .net c#?

Example:

If I have the following stored proc which will return the output variables (`@customer_id, @customer_name, @customer_address, @customer_age`) instead of the select variable, how can I read the output variable with the following?

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "EXEC app_customers @name=" + sName.Text;
mySqlConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
{
}
```

Comment: Just search fro **c# stored procedure output parameter** and the first 2 links are http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/CallStoredProcedurewithinputandoutputparameters.htm and http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/RetrievingaStoredProcedureOutputParameter.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the result is a single value (or if you're just interested in the first value in the first column), use the method `ExecuteScalar`.

It returns an object, simply cast it to the expected type.

```
int id = (int)mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Note: the way you're invoking a procedure is not the normal way to do it. Set the command to reference the stored procedure, then add appropriate parameters to the `command.Parameters` collection. Invoking the procedure using `"exec ..."` is not a best practice and may even leave you vulnerable. If you need more info on executing such a call, [start here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx)

**Edit:**

If it is truly an *output parameter* you need to capture (I believe I misread your question), then the above paragraph is even more applicable. Consider this approach:

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "app_customers";
mySqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", theValue);
var customerIdParam = mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
customerIdParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
// add more parameters, setting direction as appropriate

mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
int customerId = (int)customerIdParam.Value;
// read additional outputs
```

Comment: Parameters will also help protect you against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: how about if the output variable is more then one?

Comment: @Jin, you could try adding more parameters (should work with multiple output parameters, but I don't have experience *trying* that). However, if you are truly returning many such values, you might consider *selecting* those values and returning them as a table.